# ByteBuddy - creating proxy, but with original object as field

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I'am trying to create a proxy with ByteBuddy. Is it possible to use the InvocationHandlerAdapter but to adapt it that the original object can be hold as field too? Actually i am using it like this:

```
 Class<T> proxy = (Class<T>) byteBuddy
                .subclass(clazz)
                .name(clazz.getSimpleName() + "Implementing" + TaskOps.class.getSimpleName() + "Proxy")
                .method(ElementMatchers.isAnnotatedWith(Task.class))
                .intercept(InvocationHandlerAdapter.of(taskInvocationHandler))
                .method(ElementMatchers.isDeclaredBy(TaskOps.class))
                .intercept(InvocationHandlerAdapter.of(taskInvocationHandler.getTaskOpsInvocationHandler())).make()
                .load(clazz.getClassLoader()).getLoaded();
```

Everything works fine. But i want to keep the proxied object as field "original" in the created proxy (or in the invocation handler). Is that possible?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK, Both Mockito and Spock use ByteBuddy in order to create dynamic proxies with the delegator pattern you are describing. Maybe you want to take a look there in the source code.

Comment: Good point. For someone that doesn’t know the source code the exact parts are hard to find. Can you as contributor point to the relevant parts? I assume ByteBuddyInterceptorAdapter delegates to some implementation of IProxyBasedMockInterceptor? But which param/value represents the real object?

Comment: I am not a Mockito contributor and also did not contribute to the ByteBuddy mocks in Spock. I would also have to read the source code from scratch. Rafael should be able to answer both quickly and precisely, I consider myself at the dabbling level in BB usage. You may call me a BB dilettante or amateur.  I know how mocks based on dynamic mocks work on a high level, but I have not implemented any by myself.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Let’s see what Rafael answers... ;-)

Comment: Um, sorry, after a quick look into the Spock source code it seems that both ByteBuddy and CGLIB proxies in Spock seem to do direct subclassing without delegation. My assumption seems to have been wrong at least for Spock (not sure about Mockito's technique). But I know for sure that the CGLIB proxies used by Spring AOP use a subclass + delegate pattern. That just does not help you with BB. My bad, sorry.

Comment: I forgot to mention how interception can work without a delegate: Instead of making the subclass's method intercept & call methods from the delegate (original object) like Spring AOP does, Spock's dynamic proxies seem to use an intercept & super-call pattern. This would mean that interception should also work for self-invocation in Spock, while it does not in Spring AOP. _(Sorry, just thinking aloud here.)_ And indeed it does in Spock, which is why you can verify that self-invoked methods have been called on Spock mocks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is of course possible using the adapter's `toField` method where the fields must be of type `InvocationHandler`. You can define the field on the proxy and it's your responsibility to set an instance before taking a proxy into use.

Comment: Hi. Sorry, still can’t stick it together, I do obviously have a knot in my head. Can you give me some pseudo code please?